# issue with Iron Router/Blaze

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have been trying to use Iron Router and I have been getting this error. Looks like the blaze-layout package is the problem.

[image]

I think I need to remove the blaze-layout package. I have tried to do this but I get this :

```
$ ls
accounts-t9n  blaze-layout  font-awesome-4-less  less-bootstrap-3  simple-form    underscore-string-latest
autoform      collection2   iron-router          moment            simple-schema
graeme@ubuntu:~/bootstrapApp/packages$ meteor remove blaze-layout
blaze-layout: not in project
```

It is quite clearly there but I have noticed there is no reference to it in smart.json or smart.lock files. I tried changing the directory name of blaze-layout to something different to see if that would work but it didn't.

Should I be removing the blaze-layout package ? If so how do I do so properly ?

My Meteor version:

```
$ meteor --version
Release 0.8.3


        smart.json

    {
      "packages": {
        "less-bootstrap-3": {},
        "font-awesome-4-less": {},
        "autoform": {},
        "iron-router": "0.8.2"
      }
    }

    .meteor/packages

    standard-app-packages
    autopublish
    insecure
    less
    less-bootstrap-3
    font-awesome-4-less
    accounts-password
    accounts-ui
    accounts-twitter
    autoform
    collection2
    simple-schema


    smart.lock

    {
      "meteor": {},
      "dependencies": { 
        "basePackages": {
          "less-bootstrap-3": {},
          "font-awesome-4-less": {},
          "autoform": {},
          "iron-router": {
            "version": "0.8.2"
          }
        },
        "packages": {
          "less-bootstrap-3": {
            "git": "https://github.com/DerMambo/less-bootstrap-3.git",
            "tag": "v0.0.2",
            "commit": "b5010b2ff9e9ae6b0e6e13eb0f6c81c9cb84373e"
          },
          "font-awesome-4-less": {
            "git": "https://github.com/svub/fontawesome4-less.git",
            "tag": "v4.4.0",
            "commit": "250d2336a217c18eb70e9d074784a7db3ca38472"
          },
          "autoform": {
            "git": "https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform.git",
            "tag": "v0.17.1",
            "commit": "a4688e7d77019a68ef43c2a303e905748beeb860"
          },
          "simple-schema": {
            "git": "https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema.git",
            "tag": "v0.7.0",
            "commit": "77d267aec4ba8a70f677e5d9ef9fb91fb0e3f0f6"
          },
          "collection2": {
            "git": "https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2.git",
            "tag": "v0.4.6",
            "commit": "80554182486be0d8e74f7ed02194a5649d712e27"
          },
          "moment": {
            "git": "https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment.git",
            "tag": "v2.8.1",
            "commit": "722ea63783d594341023836b7d418ab2567dab8c"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got an outdated Iron Router version. Normally you would run `mrt update`, but since IR 0.9, incompatible with Meteor 0.8.3, is already on Atmosphere, you should update the smart.json instead.

In your smart.json file find this line:

```
"iron-router": {},
```

and replace it with:

```
"iron-router": "0.8.2",
```

If there is something inside that `{}` object, don't worry, just remove it.

After that, running `mrt` should work.

---

If the problem persist, go to `~/.meteorite/packages` and remove `blaze-layout`, `iron-router` and all `iron-*` folders. Afterwards remove the now dead links from your project `/packages` folder and run `mrt install`. This will ensure that the versions of dependencies you're using are the ones required by IR 0.8.2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've tried that and sadly I'm still getting the "too much recursion" error.  I tried removing the blaze-layout folder and all the iron-* folders, running mrt install.  Also tried mrt update and still nothing.  The blaze-layout package wasn't listed in my smart.json file and I didn't add it.  The exact error I'm getting is:  `debugFunc()(msg || 'Exception caught in template:', e.stack || e.message);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in the project root to remove packages.

```
$ cd ~/bootstrapApp
$ mrt remove blaze-layout
```

Comment: `graeme@ubuntu:~/bootstrapApp$ cd ~/bootstrapApp
graeme@ubuntu:~/bootstrapApp$ mrt remove blaze-layout`

That didn't work either, I've tried it a few times.  There must be a deeper problem somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you could attach the contents of `smart.json`, `smart.lock`, and  `.meteor/packages`.

Comment: That would indeed be useful :)  I've added this to my original post.

Comment: This is most annoying.  I tried creating a new project and adding in all the same packages, same code etc.  I get this error:

`too much recursion
http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed
Line 731` 


What I have noticed is that if I close firebug, everything works fine!  Both the new project and the old one both work, its just as soon as you open firebug everything crashes :(

Comment: Sounds like this isn't a blaze-layout issue at all. Does it work with Chrome + Devtools?

Comment: I've been playing around with iron router, got two routes working, one route displays a form and prepopulates the form with data if there is any.  I try to view on Firefox (31.0) and viewing the route with the form on it directly doesn't work at all and it also shows intermittent errors when clicking on the link to this route.  I tried on chrome - no problems at all, the dev tools work fine too!  How annoying :/  Thank you for your help!